# How to reload data in material table when state changes?

Tags: material-table

I am trying to re-render material-table when my state (props.office, props.department) changes. The data seems to reload but the page number stays the same, for example if I was on page 2 and the state changed, it calls for data for page 2 instead of calling data for page 1. Here's the code to elaborate on what I am trying to do:

```
function PastMaterialTable(props) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const tableRef = React.createRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    tableRef.current.onQueryChange();
  },[props.office, props.department])

  function questionSearch(query) {
    setIsLoading(true);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       let url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?";
       url += "per_page=" + query.pageSize;
       url += "&page=" + (query.page + 1);
       url += "&office=" + (props.office + 1);
       url += "&department=" + (props.department + 1);
       console.log("fetching data for office: " + props.office + ", department: " + props.department + " and questions of type: " + "past" + " query pagesize: " + query.pageSize + " query page: " + (query.page+1));
       fetch(url)
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(result => {
         setIsLoading(false);
         resolve({
           data: result.data,
           page: result.page - 1,
           totalCount: result.total
         });
       });  
     })
    }

    return (
    <MaterialTable
      tableRef= {tableRef}
      columns={[
        { title: "Question", field: "id", width: 400 },
        { title: "Category", field: "first_name", width: 100 },
        { title: "Date", field: "last_name", width: 100 }
      ]}
      data={questionSearch}
      isLoading={isLoading}
      options={{
        showFirstLastPageButtons: false,
        showEmptyDataSourceMessage: true,
        toolbar: false,
        pageSize: 10,
        pageSizeOptions:[10],
        sorting: false
      }}
      onRowClick={handleQuestionPopup}
    />
  );
}
```

Any input on how I can reset my query will be appreciated